# Does scp create the target folder if it does not exist

Tags: linux, bash, scp

I am wondering if scp will create the target folder if it does not exist on the remote server. For example, would this work?

```
scp -r /data/install/somefolder user@ftpserver.com:/data/install/somefolder
```

Here the folder `/data/install/somefolder` doesn't exist on ftp server, so would this command create it?

N.B. I have read about rsync but am not really sure how it works or how to use it yet.

Comment: What does the ssh/scp manual or documentation say?

Comment: You can use `rsync` instead: `rsync -r somefolder user@ftpserver.com:/path-to/a-new-folder`

Answer (score 56):

To achieve the task with ssh and scp (instead of rsync): lets break the task into 2 steps:

#### 1. Create directory if missing:

```
ssh user@ftpserver.com "mkdir -p /data/install/somefolder"
```

#### 2. Copy to it:

```
scp -r /data/install/somefolder user@ftpserver.com:/data/install/somefolder
```

---

### Put them together

```
server="user@ftpserver.com"
destiny="/data/install/somefolder"
src="/data/install/somefolder"
ssh "$server" "mkdir -p $destiny" && scp -r "$src" "$server:$destiny"
```

Comment: this will fail for sub directories.

Comment: @user2867106 `mkdir -p` the -p option creates the parent directory if missing. `scp -r` does the recursive copy. I dont see why it would fail. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @ThammeGowda thanks for the recipe! works like a charm!

Comment: This won't work if the server does provide shell access. Some servers only allow SFTP for file access.

Answer (score 25):

Short answer: no.

...but rsync does, which is why I have aliased `scp` to `rsync -Pravdtze ssh` on my box. Yes, that's a lot of switches, which in combination produces my preferred rsync behavior. As rsync does provide a very extensive set of switches and options, I suggest you do some research on it to see what fits your needs best. Man-page is a good place to start, but there are a lot of info easily available. Here's a [decent list of examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/rsync-command-examples/).

**Edit:** Actually, in that particular case you posted, the folder will be created, as that's the folder you're copying. However, if you're trying to copy it to `user@remotehost:somenonexistentfolder/somefolder`, then it will fail.

Comment: @badp Edited answer with a new link.

Comment: @Jarmund just in time ;)