# scp requires named directory to exist on target server

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, file-transfer

I'm using `scp` to upload a directory to a remote server. However, if the remote server does not have a "target" directory of the same name, I get a "No such file" error.

Failed directory upload example:

```
$ mkdir test_local
$ touch test_local/test_local.txt
$ scp -r ./test_local user@host.edu:
> scp: realpath ./test_local: No such file
> scp: upload "./test_local": path canonicalization failed
> scp: failed to upload directory ./test_local to .
```

However, if I create an empty target directory on the remote machine, the command does work and successfully updates the target directory with the contents of the local directory.

It's my understanding that `scp` should not require an empty "target" directory of the same name to exist, so why is this the case here?

This question is not a duplicate of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920947/does-scp-create-the-target-folder-if-it-does-not-exist), because the target directory (in my example, the home directory of the remote server) **does** exist. It simply doesn't share a name with the sent directory.

Comment: It may not be a duplicate, but it's definitely off-topic here as it's not a programming problem. Try [unix.se] or [su]?

Comment: I see, thanks. I'll repost there.